# TinyMCE: Some of icons don't appear

Tags: jquery, icons, tinymce

I am using *thebigreason* skin for TinyMCE (3.5.8 jQuery package):
http://thebigreason.com/blog/2008/09/29/thebigreason-tinymce-skin

The problem is **some** of icons don't appear:

[image]

I've checked it in the Firebug for the CSS and URL but no problems detected:
( *Icons that weren't appear were exist in the **icons.png** file* )

[image]

I've removed the browser's cache and checked it in all major browsers but the problem with the same result exists.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by removing some of plugins like "**advlist**". It seems that the skin doesn't support dropdowns for some icons.

You can see that this is the image with **advlist**: [image] and without it: [image]

And another thing is some of the icons in the **icons.png** file were missed:
( *like **highlight text** and **table controls*** )

Original TinyMCE: (**icons.png**)

[image]

TheBigReason Skin:  (**icons.png**)

[image]

Hope they will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php

you must add all tiny mce options this is an example :

> tinyMCE.init({
>           theme_advanced_buttons1 : "separator,insertdate,inserttime,preview,zoom,separator,forecolor,backcolor",
>           theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bullist,numlist,separator,outdent,indent,separator,undo,redo,separator",
>           theme_advanced_buttons3 : "hr,removeformat,visualaid,separator,sub,sup,separator,charmap" });

Comment: Thank you Mohamed. I've solved it and posted the answer for other friends.